# One pixel wide artefact using Bootstrap grid with backgrounds

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsiveness

I'm not going to try to explain this in words, just have a look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fhf8rwno/4/

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="myBox" style="height:100px;background-color:#000;">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    blbalbalabla
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5" style="height:100px;background-color:red;">
                    wowowowo
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

In either Chrome or Firefox (possibly other browsers too), watch the red column as you resize the browser width. You should notice that on every other change in browser side a one-pixel-wide gap appears at the right edge of the parent container, allowing the parent background to come through.

If I instead use `col-xs-6` instead of `col-xs-7` and `col-xs-5`, the issue disappears. So it seems the browser's pixel math may cause this due to the odd/even mix of column ratios.

This may not seem like much, but the site I'm working on uses this pattern a lot and half the users are seeing some very noticeable and unsightly dark lines.

Any thoughts or suggested hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: here's a hacky way of achieving this. http://jsfiddle.net/fhf8rwno/8/

CSS

```
.row.no-gutter {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0
}

.row.no-gutter [class*='col-'],
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="myBox" style="height:100px;background-color:#000;">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    blbalbalabla
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5" style="height:100px;background-color:red; position: relative; right: -1px;">
                    wowowowo
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My `no-gutter` class was already removing the margins. I still see the same issue in your modified fiddle.

Comment: @Dan weird. Does this work? I'll update my answer with the CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/fhf8rwno/7/

Comment: Ah ok I see what you're doing. Unfortunately I still need the margin on the surrounding row (the one without the no-gutter). Removing the `margin-right:0` on the no-gutter class also may seem to fix the issue in a similar way, but that too is not workable as it puts the default bootstrap gutter back on the right side of column elements. I need zero gutter on `myBox`, but gutter on its parent.

Comment: @Dan ah, okay, I see it. Here is a hacky way of doing it. https://jsfiddle.net/fhf8rwno/8/ Basically just adding `position: relative; right: -1px;` on the `col-xs-5` class.

Comment: That works, so I'll give you the checkmark, appreciate your efforts. Either the right shift or the margin shift I posted below seem to do the same job. Both ways are hack-y, but I'm not sure if anyone can come up with anything better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A colleague and I have come to a semi-solution, but I'm not going to accept this answer just yet in case someone comes up with something less hack-y.

Shifting the last column's margins by one seems to help the issue:

```
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:last-child {
    margin-right:-1px;
    margin-left:1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fhf8rwno/6/

Comment: Pretty much equivalent to @9997's answer above. Both ways are hack-ily shifting the element over to cover up the gap.